# Delphi, как создать компонент от TForm

Tags: delphi, компоненты, forms

Необходимо все формы в проекте создавать от формы потомка. Как это делается понятно. Но хочется чтобы в Object Inspector для форм можно было менять свои(дополнительные свойства).

Я пробовал создать компонент:

```
unit FjForm;

interface

uses Forms, Classes;


type
  TFjForm = class(TForm)
  private
    FSelected: boolean;
  published
    property Selected: Boolean read FSelected write FSelected;
  end;

implementation
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Fj', [TFjForm]);
end;

end.
```

Он компилируется, но в Tool Palette не появляется. Потом я создаю форму и делаю вот так

```
unit FramworkFjForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, FjForm,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm3 = class(TFjForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

В Object Inspector ничего не меняется.

Исправляю dfm
вместо object пишу inherited

После этого форма перестает открываться, пишет Error creating form: Ancestor for 'TFjForm' not found.

Конечно можно свойства прописать в форме и инициализировать их в FormCreate, но удобнее это делать в Object Inspector.
Как сделать чтобы в Object Inspector для формы можно задавать свои свойства?

Comment: А зачем форму как компонент? Просто при создании формы указываете наследоваться от такой то формы и будет всё работать.

Comment: Чтобы в Object Inspector появилось свойство. Если добавить published property в предок, то он не появляется в Object Inspector. Но он появляется когда создаешь именно компонент. Например нам нужно от базовой формы(Формы предка) создать форму с измененным свойством. Придется в конструкторе присваивать это свойство, а так можно было в Object Inspector его поставить и все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел на форумах, но не проверял. Попробуйте

1. Сделайте своство или событие публичным

   ```
   ...
   published
       property Selected: Boolean read FSelected write FSelected;
   ...
   ```
2. Добавьте форму в Object repository.
3. Создать пакет и добавить форму в пакет.
4. Добавить в пакет следующую процедуру

   ```
   interface
   ...
   procedure Register;
   implementation
   uses dsgnIntf;
   ...
   procedure Register;
   begin
     RegisterCustomModule(TMyCustomForm, TCustomModule);
   end;
   ```
5. Установите пакет
6. Создайте новую форму, которая наследуется от вашей. Откройте Object inspector и проверьте появилось ли свойство.